# Determining when a new transaction has started in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way in SQLite to determine when a new transaction has started, or which transaction is currently in progress?

The purpose for this is in a trigger which is logging certain changes to a database.  As far as I can tell, a trigger has no indication as to whether the given operation is by itself or part of a set of other operations.  Something like a transaction count would allow for a clear delineation of which changes occurred atomically at the same time (e.g. for the purpose of playback).

Comment: There is no such feature in SQLite, as far as I know. You could wrap sqlite calls into your own abstraction layer and implement it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has [commit and rollback notification callbacks](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/commit_hook.html), which are called at the *end* of any transaction.